# Required warning is indicating to the required field behind the MUI header. Is there any solution for this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, navigation-drawer, required

[image]

I'm using Drawer from MUI 5, the TextFields are also from MUI 5 with "required" props. When I leave the first name empty, the page scrolls to the top but the TextField is still behind the header. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: you should give some top padding to the form.

Comment: @ManishKumar that didn't work

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet or a codesandbox?